# Laravel 5.3 - Impossible to retrieve model ID after saving

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5.3

When saving a new model, the model object will contain information of all the columns (including the dynamically generated timestamps), but not the id.

For instance:

```
$uid = Uid::Create(['name' => 'test']);
```

or

```
$uid = new Uid; $uid->name = 'test'; $uid->save()
```

Will return `{"name":"test","updated_at":"2016-11-06 17:36:44","created_at":"2016-11-06 17:36:44"}`

The id is an increments, as I've always been doing with previous Laravel versions.

I've also tried adding `$visible = ['id']`, but wouldn't work.
Any idea why this can be happening?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems now you need to add

```
public $incrementing = true;
```

to all models...